# How to implement [String:[String]] in Kotlin coming from Swift

Tags: swift, kotlin

I am new to Kotlin and wondering how I would implement something similar to in Swift where `[String:[String]]`. Additionally how would I initialize this data structures with values in a single line.

Comment: http://nilhcem.com/swift-is-like-kotlin/

Comment: As a type, that would just be `Map<String, List<String>>`

Answer (score 1):

`val map = mapOf("key1" to listOf("", ""), "key2" to listOf())`